# A proof involving a continuous function $f$ and showing that $f(c)=f(d)=m.$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Consider a continuous function $f$ on $[a,b]$ with $f(a)=f(b).$  Define 
$$A=\sup \left \{ f(x) \mid x \in [a,b] \right \}$$
and 
$$B= \inf \left \{ f(x) \mid x \in [a,b] \right \}.$$
My goal is to prove the statement:

> If $B<m<A$, then there exists $c,d \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)=f(d)=m$ with $c$ and $d$ not equal.

I was given a hint that we can split the proof into two different cases, looking at $f(a) \neq A$ and $f(a) \neq B.$ . However, I am still a little stuck.

I know that if $f(a) \neq A$, then we can let 
$$f(a)<m<A.$$
Then we know there exists an $x_{1} \in (a,b)$ such that $f(x_{1})=A.$ . Then we can consider the sets 
$$[a,x_{1}]  \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ [x_{1},b].$$
From here I am not really sure how to continue.  Can anyone help me complete the proof in this manner?  Is there any easier way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why $c$ and $d$? If you have $c$ in hand just take $d=c$.

Comment: @aduh Sorry- I forgot to add that they cannot be the same number.

Comment: Can you not use the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: @aduh That’s what I was thinking to do, but the hint I got kinda threw me off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do the case $f(a)<A$. Since $f$ is continuous, there exists $c\in[a,b]$ such that $f(c)=A$. Since $f(a)=f(b)<A$ we have $a,b\ne c$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists $x_1\in(a,c)$ such that $f(x_1)=m$. But $f(b)=f(a)<A$, and there exists $x_2\in(c,b)$ such that $f(x_2)=m$. It is clear that $x_1\ne x_2$.